# Strange behavior in C++, cout statement is required to prevent app crash?

Tags: c++, cout

I am attempting to solve an algorithm problem but am witnessing strange behavior. Whenever I comment out the first cout statement as it seemed relatively benign and only there for testing purposes my script does not run. It will compile without errors but when I run with a txt file input parameter it crashes.

However, if I leave the cout statement in the script below it runs fine with no problems. I am not sure why this is happening. Again the script works but not as intended when commenting out a seemingly non-essential cout statement. What am I missing here?

**Test input file**

```
5
9 6
4 6 8 
0 7 1 5
```

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    ifstream stream(argv[1]);
    string line;
    while (getline(stream, line)) 
    {

        cout<<line<<" String representation."<<endl;  // Why do i need to keep this to prevent segfault / AppCrash (windows)?
        vector<long int> numbers = string_to_ints(line);

        for (int i =0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            cout<<numbers.at(i)<<" ";
        }
        cout<<" number representation."<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

string_to_ints() declaration below

```
vector<long int> string_to_ints(string input) // takes string input and produces a list of ints
{

    char* buffer;

    stringstream ss(input);

    vector<long int> tokens;

    while (ss >> buffer)
    {
        tokens.push_back(atol(buffer)); // creates a vector of ints
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

I am using gcc version 4.8.1

Comment: What is the crash? What does it say?

Comment: You are reading into an uninitialized pointer (`char* buffer`). Use a std::string instead.

Comment: Just read the numbers into a `long`. `long a; while( ss >> a ) tokens.push_back( a );`

Comment: Or you can use the char buffer[SIZE] approach

Comment: I used type char* because atol() wouldn't accept a std::string. Ohhhh wait a minute. I changed the code and used `std::string buffer;` and then changed `atol()` to `atoi(buffer.c_str())` and now everything is working as expected. Wow that was pretty tricky for me. Thanks @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: Since you are using a stringstream why not ouput the stream to an long int in the first place?

Comment: @NathanOliver there's a thought. But probably because I am still wet behind the ears when it comes to Cplus. I will look into that though, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you never allocate memory for `buffer` in `string_to_ints`. Since this is undefined behavior *anything* can happen, includiing appearing to work when a cout is in place and not working when the cout is removed.

The simplest solution is to use `std::string` instead of `char*` for your buffer. Then you avoid doing your own memory management.

Comment: Thanks @Mark B between your answer and Ulrich Eckhardt's suggestion I was able to figure out what to do. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708760/strange-behavior-in-c-cout-statement-is-required-to-prevent-app-crash?noredirect=1#comment43829437_27708760).